# unity セーブキーを変数のように変更したい

Tags: unity3d

現在カレンダーを作っています。
日付ごとにイベントを保存したいのです。

セーブキーを日付にして、毎回変更できるようにしたいです。
playerPref.Setintでは、キーを変更する事はできません。
良いセーブ方法はありませんか？

Answer (score 0):

すみません、ソースコードを載せて、ここでこういう事をしたいって感じの方が答えやすいです。

とりあえず、PlayerPrefsはいろんなものを保存する事ができます、int型でもstring型でも。
https://docs.unity3d.com/ja/current/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html

```
PlayerPrefs.SetString("Name", m_PlayerName);
```

こんな風に。